# Is it possible to have a setting that keeps the lnk files in the Recent folder only for a number of days

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, citrix, thin-client

In our organization we see that the Recent folder in `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` is growing and growing. But that is because it is used over a couple of years probably. Now my question is, is there some way we can have a setting to keep only the lnk files of the last 5 days for example in stead of everything?
Some additional important information. We work with Thinclients that connect to a citrix farm through Xenapp.

EDIT

We work also with RES Workspace manager to manage all the accounts and what they can do and cannot do. Maybe this can also be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a scheduled task can help you clean up the list. First you need to create a batch file to clean up older entries. Here is the sample code:

```
forfiles /p %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent /d -5 /C "CMD /c del /A -RSH @path"
```

/d -5 means "older than 5 days"

Then open windows task scheduler and create a basic task, specify any trigger you want (i.e. weekly or "when I log on") and specify that batch file

Please test before using in production.